# How send JSON data from html to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, android-webview

I'm trying to send JSON data from html to javascript function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />"
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"roboto.css\">
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"webViewLightTheme.css\">
</head>
<body>
    <img src=\"http://x.y.z/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/android-smart-text-selection-350x175.jpg\" onClick=\"window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages( \"[{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}]\" );\" />"
</body>
</html>
```

But on image click I'm getting this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

I want to know how to send JSON data from html part to javascript part.

Comment: "_from html function to javascript function_"?? HTML does not have functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unrecommended:

```js
console.log('onclick= '+document.images[0].getAttribute('onclick'));
window.JavaScriptInterface={}
window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages=function(x){console.log(x)}
document.images[0].click()
```

```html
<img src="http://x.y.z/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/android-smart-text-selection-350x175.jpg\" onclick='window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages("[{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}]")'>
```

better use `addEventListener` like @Reijo did,

Comment: `<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-520" src="http://x.x.x.x/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/facebook-messenger.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="374"  onerror='this.onerror=null;this.src='file:///android_res/drawable/image_background.png';'  onClick='window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages("[{"image":"http://x.x.x.x/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/facebook-messenger.jpg","imageCaption":""}]");' />` 
by doing this I got this error 
`"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source: file:///android_asset/`

Comment: @KapilJindal,try this: <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-520" src="http://x.x.x.x/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/facebook-messenger.jpg" alt="" width="750" height="374" onerror='this.onerror=null;this.src="file:///android_res/drawable/image_background.png";' onClick='window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages("[{"image":"http://x.x.x.x/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/facebook-messenger.jpg","imageCaption":""}]");' />

Comment: `<img src="android-smart-text-selection-350x175.jpg" onClick='window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages("[{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}]");' />`

gives this error :
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source: file:///android_asset/`

Comment: @KapilJindal,try this: <img src="android-smart-text-selection-350x175.jpg" onclick='window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages("[{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}]");' />

Comment: But I'm getting `[{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}]` by converting JSON to string using `JSON.stringify(data)` so how could I generate like `[{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}]` mentioned?

Comment: @KapilJindal, JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"/g,'\\"')

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working sample.

```js
function process(json) {
  // Do whatever you want with the json object
  // Example
  console.log(json[0].name);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />"
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"roboto.css\">
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"webViewLightTheme.css\">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://x.y.z/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/android-smart-text-selection-350x175.jpg" onClick="process([{'name':'John', 'age': '30', 'city':'New York'}]);" />"
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [JSON library](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
const img = document.getElementById('img');
img.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let jsonString = '"[{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}]';
  window.JavaScriptInterface.showImages(JSON.parse(jsonString));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes in the JSON data are interfering with the sticks quotes for the attributes. You need to escape the divide quotes in the JSON data again (add a `\`) so that both the enclosing quite we aren't seeing and the HTML parser know that the double quotes in the JSON data are part of the data you're passing in, and not meant to end a quote.

EDIT: Alternatively you could use single quotes, the way you do in the viewport tag, because neither HTML nor Javascript differentiate between single and double quotes. This might make the whole thing less confusing and easier to read.